When is it appropriate to bring up asking for a raise again?
My boyfriend has been at his job for three months. He works in construction. He asked his boss for a three dollar raise. His response was they’re not bringing in enough money right now. He said he had to talk to his people. It has been over a week. How long does he wait…when is it appropriate to bring it up again?
He felt his starting pay was too low to begin with, so he felt three months was enough time to prove his worth. His boss has him traveling for work, running projects by himself…in general taking on more responsibilities. Hope that helps.

What were his reasons for asking for a raise to begin with? Or was it 'just because'? We will need to know more of the context if you want specifics, otherwise you're going to get vague answers or no answers at all.

He felt his starting pay was too low to begin with, so he felt three months was enough time to prove his worth. His boss has him traveling for work, running projects by himself…in general taking on more responsibilities. Hope that helps

You don't address this, but why do you feel that your BF deserves a raise?  That is very important.
If you are having budgetary troubles, that is not the employers responsibility and not a good basis to ask for a raise.
If your boyfriend has gained new skills or certifications in the last three months, then sure that might be a good reason to ask for a raise if the employer can earn more from those skills or certifications.
If your BF is being paid below market wages for his skills or experience, and he agreed to be paid lower temporarily then that time frame is when the discussion needs to occur.
Typically raises are given out after a year or so of experience is customary.
However, your BF might be able to get a raise by seeking out employment elsewhere.  Will a different construction project/company pay him more?

Economic conditions for a company don't change in a week. If you push for a rapid answer, it is likely to be no.
Focus on finding out what your manager needs to see from you to justify a raise, and understanding the time frame during which that decision will be made.
In many companies, raises are only considered once a year. Your industry may be different, or it may not be.

It's always appropriate to ask for a raise if you think you have the leverage to get one. If you don't then there's not much point asking a second time and a potential danger.
Any time you ask for a raise or pretty much anything else there is an underlying assumption that you may quit if your needs are not met. This can lead an employer to start looking for your replacement. If you're bluffing and it gets called you just lost all your negotiating strength then and going forwards.
So when you ask for something, be serious about it, prepare a strategy if denied at the very least.
